# Firefox addons to highlight all external links on a page

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, highlighting

Are there any Firefox addons that highlight all external links on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) script for that. You can install it from [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/28901).

Comment: Since userscripts.org is down, here is mirrors from [userscripts-mirror.org](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/28901) and [internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20131104173942/http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/28901)